# Is it possible to extend the selection with additional lines so that each group has the same number of rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to extend selection by additional rows
For example I have an incoming dataset:

Select * from SomeTable

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          Type       |        Value     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         null     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         null     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         null     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         null     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         null     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         null     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         null     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I want to extend it up to 3 rows per group when Type is a group key

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          Type       |        Value     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         null     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         null     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         null     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         null     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         null     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         null     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         null     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         null     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         null     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         null     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         null     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         null     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cross apply`.  Assuming no types have more than 3 rows already:

```
select ty.type, t.value
from (values (1), (2), (3)) v(n) cross join
     (select distinct type from t) ty left join
     (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by type order by value) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
     on t.type = ty.type and t.seqnum = v.n
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't particularly pretty, but it does the job. If you have a table with the unique types in it, it'll likely be more performant, as the `DISTINCT` won't be needed:

```sql
WITH Types AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           ST.[Type],
           V.RN
    FROM dbo.SomeTable ST
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1),(2),(3))V(RN))
RNs AS(
    SELECT [Type],
           [Value],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN --As it appears you have no unique ID in your table I use SELECT NULL
    FROM dbo.SomeTable)
SELECT T.[Type,
       R.[Value]
FROM Types T
     LEFT JOIN RNs R ON T.RN = R.RN;
```